# Top N by categories

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am working on the below calculation; I have tried different solutions but not able to get the required output.
The sample table looks like below with ID, Amount, Category, Type;

[image]

I have a pie chart that shows the split of cash and card. Also, I created a measure to identify the average amount by each category like below.

```
AverageExpenseType = 
    AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE('Data',
            'Data'[Category],
            "Total Spent", AVERAGE('Data'[Amount])),
        [Total Spent])
```

What I need to create is a table where the Top 5 ID's amount is more than the average to the respective Category and Type. i.e., when I select Cash in the pie chart, the average needs to calculated based on the cash or card as well.

For eg. the average of category A for cash is 4710 and the output looks like below where the ID having more than the average for Category A and Cash type

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample output you wants? And please add some more sample data as you are looking for top 10 value.

Comment: @mkRabbani Apologies for the delay. I have updated the sample data and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a custom column  in your table with this below code-

```
category_type_wise_average = 

VAR current_category = pie_chart[category]
VAR current_type = pie_chart[type]

VAR category_wise_average = 
AVERAGEX(
    FILTER(
        pie_chart,
        pie_chart[category] = current_category
            && pie_chart[type] = current_type
    ),
    pie_chart[amount]
)

RETURN category_wise_average
```

Now you will have the Category and Type wise Average value in each row as shown in the below image. You can now apply your necessary filtering as per your requirements.

[image]

**SOLUTION 2:**
Now, if you feel there is performance issue in generation a custom column with average calculation for every row, you can try this below option with same result-

**Step-1:**
Create a new custom table with this below code-

```
pie_group_average = 

VAR sub_category_wise_total = 
GROUPBY (  
    pie_chart,
    pie_chart[category],
    pie_chart[type],
    "average",AVERAGEX(CURRENTGROUP(), pie_chart[amount])    
) 

RETURN
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    sub_category_wise_total,
    "category",pie_chart[category],
    "type",pie_chart[type],
    "average",[average] 
)
```

**Step-2:**
Now create a **Custom Column** in your main table as below-

```
category_type_wise_average_2 = LOOKUPVALUE(
    pie_group_average[average],   
    pie_group_average[category],pie_chart[category],
    pie_group_average[type],pie_chart[type]
)
```

This measure will now hold the same value we generated in solution-1 with custom column.

**Additional Steps:**

**Step-3:**
Please create another custom column as-

```
show_hide = 
IF(
    pie_chart[amount] >= pie_chart[category_type_wise_average_2], 
    1, 
    0
)
```

**Step-4:**
Add these 2 visual level filter as shown in the below image-

[image]

Step by step change in data showing will be as below-

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: I tried to replicate the solution 2 and I am getting error on the step 2 part. The error is "A single value for column 'Category' in table pie_chart cannot be determined.  Also it looks mentioning something like 'values without specifying an aggregation'. I am not sure if I missed anything.

Comment: did you created the custom table first in step 1?

Comment: Yes I have created the custom table and got the average values perfectly

Comment: please provide me the custom table and measure creation code here if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to restrictions I may not able to share the custom table :-(

Comment: But this is clearly looks like I am not getting the measure names while entering 'pie_chart[category]' in the step 2. However, if i wrap it with some function this drop down is coming. Not sure if this helps

Comment: Hi @ssan, I made a mistake in the instruction. In second step, you need to create a custom column as well. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219724/discussion-between-ssan-and-mkrabbani).